# Angularjs checkbox checked ng-change no action

Tags: angularjs

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="activeStatus" 
       ng-checked="outlet2Datas.INT_EXTEND_1 == 1"
       ng-change="setOutletStatus(activeStatus)"
       ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />
```

Controller

```
    $scope.setOutletStatus = function (activeStatus) {
        console.log(activeStatus);
    }
```

I am new for angularjs, and I need some help about checkbox ng-change.

This is the HTML checkbox input. I get the value from API to checked the checkbox when the value is 1. When the checkbox value start from 1 means the checkbox is checked, I click the checkbox the console nothing come out. And I click again the checkbox the console return the value 1 and click again the value is 0. Why the ng-change can't do action for the first time when the checkbox is checked but it can do action when the checkbox is unchecked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked)
you shouldn't use `ngModel` with `ngChecked`. Because this can lead to unexpected behavior. Seems that happens in your case.

You can just assign `true` or `false` to variable, that you pass to `ng-model` directive. Or any other value, but it should be same as one of declared values in `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` directives.

Also you don't need to pass your model variable as a parameter to `ng-change` callback. Because you already have access to this variable in your `$scope`.

Basically, I prepare [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/hebaweniza/edit?html,js,output) for you, with working example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination for my question. I get to solve my probelm with your example. Thank you very much.